# In a nice protomodular category, is normality stable under joins?

Tags: category-theory, normal-subgroups

Call a subobject *normal* if it's an equivalence class of some internal equivalence relation on the codomain. In a finitely complete category, normality is closed under finite intersection and finite product and is also pullback stable. This can be proved using a metatheorem which reduces to verification in the category of sets.

In the category of groups, normality is also closed under joins in the subobject poset (see [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/370366/223002)). Is the finite analogue of this state true in some nice protomodular categories, e.g homological ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3909) of Tomas Everaert and Tim Van der Linden shows that it is true for semi-abelian categories (see Proposition 2.7). Exactness implies that every normal monomorphism is a kernel, and they need the existence of coproduct to define joins of subobjects; so I'm not sure that this would still hold in a category that is only homological.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!